# Organic Shape Detection and measuring (PHP,JS ... or other)

Tags: php, computer-vision

The picture:

http://img511.imageshack.us/i/measuring1and2space.gif/

We have a .gif Picture.
We want to measure the size of the 3 black island (2) in relation to the big white "ocean" (1). (3) is the background- we must consider it as border for (1), but we dont want to measure it. (0) is the *chosen* main area (in this case (1)), which should be used as the reference area for measuring. So in this case (0) is in (1), which itself is therefore 100% (reference). So the three islands are about xx% of the size of (0). If (0) is in (2), then (1) is Xxx% of the island(s).

Ok...lets say:

1. User takes (0) in (1). Lets imagine he is using JS, and drag'n'drops the red dot into the white area. The red dot detects the color of the area under it.
2. Now the system needs to detect the whole white area, set it as (0) and give it 100%. The system has to distinguish between (2) and (3). Therefore it is possible to measure the relation between the size of (2) and (1).

---

I cannot imagine how such algorithm can be possible in PHP. It would be awesome, but I think that...if possible...something like OpenCV is a better solution. Unfortunately I have no experience with it. I tried to code some CV in PHP, and it would be doable if there would be geometrical shapes, but these are organic.

Could you give me some direction. I don't know where to go. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php to load an image and get a single pixels color.

- count all the black pixels
- count all the black pixels from region 3

now you can calculate region 2 and also region 1

to count all the black pixels form region 3 just go trough each line. if everything is black, count everything. if not, count from left and from right all black pixels.